# How to display subscribers post in div differently like youtube does on homepage?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some project but stuck in between. Basically I am trying to get users post in a div, but I want that in one div I only get data on one specific user whom I follow and loop this query so that it show post of another user whom I follow in div.

But I am get results as list of users I follow in one div only, I want it to show differently basically there should number of divs equal to number of users I follow with title of div as username.

Query I run :

I have 3 tables :

=> |Table | 1 | username |

```
 |ID    | USERNAME | SUBSCRIBERS |
 |------|----------|-------------|
 |1     | USER1    | 5000     
 |2.    | USER2    | 10000   |
```

=> |Table | 2 | subscribers |

```
 |ID   | subscriber_from | subscriber_to  |
 |------|-----------------------------|---------------------|
 |1     | User_example     | USER1           |
 |2.    | User_example    | USER2          |
----------------------------------------------
```

=> |Table | 3 | post |

```
 |ID   | POST_CONTENT | USERNAME | VIEWS
 |------|-----------------------------|---------------------|
 |1     | This is post no.1   | USER1             |  500
 |2.    | This is post no.2   | USER2          |600
 |3     | This is post no.3   | USER2          |200
 |4     | This is post no.4   | USER1          |800
```

My query is

```
$sql = " SELECT * 
FROM subscribers 
INNER JOIN post 
    ON subscribers.subscriber_to=post_username 
WHERE subscribe_from='User_example ";
```

My output :

```
This is post no.1 
This is post no.2
This is post no.3 
This is post no.4
```

But I want it to be arranged in div user wise:

[image: Like this]

NOW I am planning it to be like when " User_example " log in his account. I want to display his followers/subscribers post to display in div. BUT should display all post of particular user in one div and all another in other div and so on in order of latest post by that user.

PHP code :

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databse");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. "
                . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM subscribers INNER JOIN post ON subscribers.subscribe_to=post.username WHERE subscribe_from='user_example' ORDER BY post.views DESC";


if($res = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){   
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
               echo $row["post_content"].$row["username"].'<br>';
        }

        mysqli_free_result($res);
    } else{
        echo "No Matching records are found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " 
                                . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);


?>
```

Comment: Order by on the subscriber and do a break sort on the subscriber in your php code. If you want help, edit your question and add the php code that you have tried.

Comment: any code pls that hepl me

Comment: Read the last sentence in my comment.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: i have put code now pls check it and direct me pls

Comment: **Order by on the subscriber and do a break sort on the subscriber in your php code**. i didnt understood this//

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The ORDER BY clause is used in MySQL to sort the results. A break-sort outputs some code only when the value of a particular field (or fields) changes.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databse");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. "
                . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//  Add order by clause to sort results by username so they can be grouped by username in output.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM subscribers INNER JOIN post ON subscribers.subscribe_to = post.username WHERE subscribe_from='user_example' ORDER BY post.username;";

if($res = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
        $lastusername = "";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            //  Break-sort. Output only when value of username changes.
            if($lastusername != $row["username"]) {
                if($lastusername != '') {
                    //  Close previous div
                    echo "</div>\n";
                }
                echo "<div class='someclass'>\n";
                $lastusername = $row["username"];
            }
            echo $row["post_content"].$row["username"].'<br>';
        }
        //  Close last div.
        echo "</div>\n";
        mysqli_free_result($res);
    } else{
        echo "No Matching records are found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " 
                                . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: ONE LITTLE HELP..I have order div ,Now i want to order post inside div .

Comment: If it helped, accept the answer. If you want to do further sorting, lookup the order by clause. Learn to research, if you want to be a programmer, that's the one skill that you will find most valuable.

Comment: pls help SIR . I AM STUCK

Comment: Seriously? You can't understand the order by clause? Did you even lookup the syntax for a SELECT statement? Or maybe the order by clause? If you want the code written for you, maybe you should consider hiring someone to do it for you.

Comment: IF I DO RESEARCH I WILL END UP MY DAY FINDING NOTHING BELIEVE ME

Comment: BTW, all caps is considered yelling, and very rude. If you can't lookup something as simple as the order by clause in MySQL, then maybe programming is not for you. If your research yields no results, then you don't know how to do research. Based on your comments, then, yes I do believe you. As mentioned before, SO is not a code writing service. People here offer to help those who at least try. But if you won't even try, then don't waste our time.

Comment: Did you bother to read the comments in the code? Or just blindly copy and paste?

Comment: i have tried all stuffs but not working.when i oder post by views the post show in different div bcoz they are up and downs in views of the specific post.BUT when i GROUP the post.username AND also ORDER post.views DESC it is showing 1 post in each user div.

Comment: It might be easy Sir but for me as a beginner it is very difficult . hope u r understanding me.

Comment: *i have tried all stuffs but not working* is not only vague, but useless. What have you tried, what isn't working. Don't answer in a comment. Edit your question. I'm done answering your comments/questions. You're ungrateful and unwilling to try. You didn't even accept the answer which was *very helpful*.

Comment: Yes, I'm understanding you. You refuse to lookup the simplest things or try anything on your own.

Comment: thank u 4 believing in me sir grateful of u . i have edited the question

Comment: i have added ORDER BY post.views DESC

Comment: AS u said it will close div once username is changed that why is it is showing some post in some div and some in another.

Comment: I have upvoted this for the specific realisation that the question author is seeking free work. It is a significant risk on Stack Overflow, and puts off good people from wanting to help.

Comment: @user10043958: please refrain from begging, SHOUTING, and abbreviated txtspk (pls, u). If you want people to make an effort for you, make an effort when writing - especially since Stack Overflow is not a chatroom. Please write words in full (you, please), use a spell-checker, and above all, do not refrain from researching on the basis that a volunteer on the internet might grant you some free labour. You won't learn anything that way.

Comment: i m sorry guys.